# arrayList.remove method not working in java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a swing application in java and I have a List and I want to search an object in the List and want to delete the passed object.

When a Update button is pressed then this action gets happened in my SWING application:

```
private void updateBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        Branch b=new Branch(address.getText(),email.getText(),name.getText(),webadd.getText(),phonenum.getText());
        
        Secretary s=new Secretary(sec.getId(),username.getText(),
         password.getText(),b);
        System.out.println("id is"+sec.getId());
       boolean result=secDao.delete(sec);
       
       if(result){
            secDao.insert(s);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Update Successful");
            fetch();
       }
       else{
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cannot Update");
       }
            
    }
```

I am making a new object `Secretary s` and `sec` is the object that I fetched from Jtable in swing.

So,since I am not using any database I am reading and writing in file,then my old object `sec` needs to be deleted and the new object `s` needs to be inserted.

So,In my SecretaryDAOImpl.java class i have the delete function working as:

```
  @Override
    public boolean delete(Secretary t) {
        System.out.print("Object passed is"+t);
         List<Secretary> secList=getAll();
//         List<Secretary> toBeRemoved=new ArrayList<>();
//         toBeRemoved.add(t);
//         secList.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
//         System.out.println("secList after remove is"+secList);
        for(int i=0;i<secList.size();i++){
            System.out.println("From delete me"+secList.indexOf(t));
        } 
         
//    for(int i=0;i<secList.size();i++){
//          Secretary s=secList.get(i);
//          if(s.getId()==t.getId()){
//              secList.remove(t);
//          }
//    }
         
         File file = new File(filename);
        if(file.delete()) 
        { 
            System.out.println("File deleted successfully");
            insertAgain(secList);
            return true;
        } 
        else
        { 
            System.out.println("Failed to delete the file"); 
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I tried out these commented line,but the object is not being deleted from list.
My `getAll();` method is returning me List:

```
 @Override
    public List<Secretary> getAll() {

try {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);
    ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(file);
    List<Secretary> secList=new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        try { 
            Secretary obj = (Secretary)reader.readObject();
            System.out.println(obj);
            secList.add(obj);
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("end of reader file ");
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("secList is"+secList);
    file.close();
    reader.close();
    return secList;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("failed to read " + filename + ", "+ ex);
}
return null;
    }
```

So,in my console,I am seeing:

```
id is2
Object passed isSecretary{id=2, userName=asdas, password=adad, branch=com.npsc.entity.Branch@5f8ea9f6}Secretary{id=2, userName=asdas, password=adad, branch=com.npsc.entity.Branch@305b8802}
secList is[Secretary{id=2, userName=asdas, password=adad, branch=com.npsc.entity.Branch@305b8802}]
From delete me-1
File deleted successfully
insert called
end of reader file 
end of reader file 
Secretary{id=2, userName=asdas, password=adad, branch=com.npsc.entity.Branch@47292e6d}
secList is[Secretary{id=2, userName=asdas, password=adad, branch=com.npsc.entity.Branch@47292e6d}]
```

My object is not being deleted from list? Why is this happening?

Comment: Why do you print "end of reader file"  when catching an exception, something has gone wrong and you just ignore the error and prints a irrelevant text? And maybe you should ask yourself why "end of reader file" is printed twice. Time to use the debugger perhaps?

Comment: ok thank you i made it